# AsynsTask  и  явный  вызов  активности

Tags: android

Доброго  времени  суток
Делаю  активити  которое  в  отдельном  потоке  проверяет  наличие  бд  и  запускает  определенную  активность  в  зависимости  от  существования  бд.
Код:

```
 package ru.systemtehnolodgi.stav;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class LoadingPage extends Activity {

    LoadingPageTask lp_task;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loading_page);

        lp_task = new LoadingPageTask();
        lp_task.execute();
    }
        Intent  intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        static final Uri TOOL_URI = Uri.parse("content://ru.htsprovider.htspdata/dataplasma");

        Cursor cursor;
    class LoadingPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            cursor = getContentResolver().query(TOOL_URI, null, null, null, null);

            if(cursor.getCount() == 0){

            }
            if(cursor.getCount() != 0){

                //startActivity(intent);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Приложение  падает.
Правильно  ли  я  понимаю  что  в создаваемом  потоке  нельзя  запускать  приложения?
И как  организовать  подобную  авантюру?

Comment: Хотя  учитывая  что  это  пусковое  приложение  можно  организовать  все  в  одном  потоке

Comment: вынести создание активити в onPostExecute

Comment: есть класс Handler